# Plot date and time interval and duration

Tags: date, plot, time, gnuplot, intervals

I have a  list of date+time start and stop that I would like to plot as bars. The X-axis should go from 00:00-23:59 with date on the Y-axis

I tried plotting in `gnuplot`, but my skills are not good enough.

The data is in the following format:

`Date            Start   Stop
06.03.2019  09:45   11:17
06.03.2019  14:40   15:20
07.03.2019  08:35   10:15
07.03.2019  14:05   14:45
08.03.2019  09:15   10:20
08.03.2019  13:55   14:45
09.03.2019  08:55   09:50
09.03.2019  13:15   14:36
10.03.2019  09:05   10:00`

I would like to get a plot similar like this, but dates on the Y-axis and all bars in the same plot. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A98t2.png.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might be a starting point. The bars are plotted with `with boxxyerror`. In this code, days without entries will not appear as label on the y-axis. Intervals which cross midnight need to be handled differently.

**Code:**

```
### plot start stop times
reset session

$Data <<EOD
06.03.2019  09:45   11:17
06.03.2019  14:40   15:20
07.03.2019  08:35   10:15
07.03.2019  14:05   14:45
08.03.2019  09:15   10:20
08.03.2019  13:55   14:45
09.03.2019  08:55   09:50
09.03.2019  13:15   14:36
10.03.2019  09:05   10:00
12.03.2019  01:01   12:59
13.03.2019  00:00   23:59
EOD

$SpecialEvents <<EOD
08.03.2019  8:00
11.03.2019  4:00
13.03.2019  12:00
EOD

StartDay = "06.03.2019"
DaysAfterStartDay(day) = int((strptime("%d.%m.%Y",day)-strptime("%d.%m.%Y",StartDay))/86400)

set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M"

plot $Data u (timecolumn(2)):(y=DaysAfterStartDay(strcol(1))): \
    (timecolumn(2)):(timecolumn(3)):(y-0.2):(y+0.2):ytic(1) w boxxyerror \
    fs solid 1.0 lc rgb "blue" notitle, \
    $SpecialEvents u (timecolumn(2)):(DaysAfterStartDay(strcol(1))):ytic(1) \
    with points pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb "red" notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: theozh, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much! If I may come with a follow up question; In addition I have a bunch of date & time that I would like to draw on the same plot, but as points (not bars). Is this easy to achieve? E.g.plot a symbol at `08.03.2019 08:00'. Also, how do I change the X-axis to range from e.g. 06:00 to 20:00 instead of 00:00 - 23:59?

Comment: this is no big thing... see modified answer with "SpecialEvents". Insert `set xrange["06:00":"20:00"]`

Answer (score 1):

There is a Gantt chart demo in the on-line collection.

```
#
# Very simple Gantt Chart
# Demonstrate using timecolumn(N,format) to plot time data from 
# multiple columns
#
$DATA << EOD
#Task start      end
A     2012-11-01 2012-12-31
B     2013-01-01 2013-03-14
C     2013-03-15 2014-04-30
D     2013-05-01 2013-06-30
E     2013-07-01 2013-08-31
F1    2013-09-01 2013-10-31
F2    2013-09-01 2014-01-17
F3    2013-09-01 2014-01-30
F4    2013-09-01 2014-03-31
G1    2013-11-01 2013-11-27
G2    2013-11-01 2014-01-17
L     2013-11-28 2013-12-19
M     2013-11-28 2014-01-17
N     2013-12-04 2014-03-02
O     2013-12-20 2014-01-17
P     2013-12-20 2014-02-16
Q     2014-01-05 2014-01-13
R     2014-01-18 2014-01-30
S     2014-01-31 2014-03-31
T     2014-03-01 2014-04-28
EOD

set xdata time
timeformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
set format x "%b\n'%y"

set yrange [-1:]
OneMonth = strptime("%m","2")
set xtics OneMonth nomirror
set xtics scale 2, 0.5
set mxtics 4
set ytics nomirror
set grid x y
unset key
set title "{/=15 Simple Gantt Chart}\n\n{/:Bold Task start and end times in columns 2 and 3}"
set border 3

T(N) = timecolumn(N,timeformat)

set style arrow 1 filled size screen 0.02, 15 fixed lt 3 lw 1.5

plot $DATA using (T(2)) : ($0) : (T(3)-T(2)) : (0.0) : yticlabel(1) with vector as 1, \
     $DATA using (T(2)) : ($0) : 1 with labels right offset -2
```

[image]