# plot data at same Yrange

Tags: gnuplot

I have this data :

```
Channel1 3 5
Channel1 1 2
Channel2 1 3
```

My goal is to plot the values of `Channel1` on the same line , I have tried to get inspiration from this question : [Plot date and time interval and duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926835/plot-date-and-time-interval-and-duration/55927762#55927762) but `Channel1` is present 2 times on Y-axis

```
set terminal png size 1920,240 transparent
set output "plot.png"
$DATA << EOD
Channel1 3 5
Channel1 1 2
Channel2 1 3
EOD
set style fill solid
boxwidth = 0.5
plot $DATA using (($2+$3)/2.):0:(($3-$2)/2.):(boxwidth/2.):yticlabels(1) w boxxyerrorbars notitle
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your keyword is simply `Channel+<number>` you can define a function to extract this number.
In the example below, e.g. Channel 3 is missing, so there will be a gap.
If your keywords are arbitrary then you would have to build a unique list of this keywords (something like a hash-table or dictionary) and assign numbers. This would also be possible in gnuplot but a bit more "complicated".

**Code:**

```
### a simple chart with keywords
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Channel1 3.0 5.0
Channel2 1.0 2.0
Channel1 1.1 2.2
Channel4 2.7 3.5
Channel5 0.2 1.3
Channel5 2.6 4.3
EOD

myY(col) = int(strcol(col)[strlen("Channel")+1:])

set style fill solid 1.0
boxwidth = 0.5
set offsets 0.1,0.2,0.5,0.5
plot $Data u (($2+$3)/2.):(myY(1)):(($3-$2)/2.):(boxwidth/2.):yticlabels(1) \
       w boxxyerrorbars lc rgb "web-green" notitle

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]